# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2^{1/n} - 1)$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(2^{1/n}-1\right)$$
converges.

I am fairly certain that this converges.  Using the ratio or root test does not seem to work.  Therefore the other tests I am left with are **alternating series test**, **intergral test**, **comparison test** and **limit comparison test** (that we know about).

Seems like it would be a messy integral and that would not work or I would not be able to solve it.
I think I could show this using the alternating series test IF the limit of the series is 0.  My problem is formally showing that the limit of this series is 0.  I can't quite get past that.
My only option left if the alternating series test does not work is the limit comparison test, since the series is not > 0 for large n, and therefore we cannot use the comparison test.  If this is the case I honestly don't have a clue what other series I should compare this with.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Expressions in the exponents need to be enclosed by `{` and `}`, not parentheses. Also, you should include the actual question in the body of the message, don't realy exclusively on the title.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the Alternating Series Test. The test asks you to check what happens to the *terms*, not what happens to the series.

Comment: +1 for explaining what you've done and where you are stuck.

Comment: +1 for the same reason as Qiaochu. Also, if you click the "edit" link you can see how Arturo fixed the exponent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an alternating series, so it suggests (nay, *screams*) for the use of the Alternating Series Test. You need to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(2^{1/n}-1) = 0$, and that for all sufficiently large $n$, $2^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1 \lt 2^{1/n} - 1$.

The latter is equivalent to showing that $2^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}$; you might want to consider taking logarithms, say base $2$, which respect the order (that is, if $0\lt a\lt b$, then $\log_2(a)\lt\log_2(b)$). As to the former, it amounts to showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{1/n} = 1$. Since $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$, this is equivalent to showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(2)}{n}} = 1$; and since the exponential is continuous, this amounts to checking what happens to the exponent as $n\to\infty$.

Note also that none of the other tests that you mention are even applicable! The integral test can only be applied to a series $\sum a_n$ in which all terms $a_n$ are nonnegative (which is not the case here), and where you can find a positive, decreasing, and continuous function $f(x)$ such that $f(n)=a_n$ for all $n$ (or at least all sufficiently large $n$). So it is not applicable here. The Comparison Test requires the series to have positive terms, as does the Limit Comparison Test. You *could* combine them with the Absolute Convergence Test by checking the convergence of $\sum|a_n|$, and then deducing the convergence of $\sum a_n$ if the series of absolute values converges, and apply one of these tests to the series $\sum|a_n|$. But you cannot apply any of the Integral, Comparison, or Limit Comparison Tests to this series directly.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gone deaf from all those expressions "screaming" at you. :)

Comment: Thanks. Your advice is always incredibly helpful and you always find the errors in the things I forget ie series needs to be positive for large n to apply some tests etc.

Comment: Oh. I just realized. I also have to show that the series is not absolutely convergent. I worded my question very poorly, since it asks weather it diverges, converges, or absolutely converges. But now it looks like a matter of showing it's absolutely convergent. I will try some tests and post results.

Comment: At the moment I have $lim 2(n^{(2/n)-1})$ from using l'hospitals once.  Anything we can do with this?

Comment: Awesome by the root test the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @J.M. I had a professor who used to talk about "the little voice inside your head that whispers to you (fill in the technique/theorem/idea)". I think my students are deafer than I used to be, because they don't seem to hear the little voice unless it's screaming...

Answer (score 3):

A general suggestion: There are a few problems asking for convergence of divergence of series of the form $\sum_n (-1)^ng(n)$ or $\sum_n g(n)$ for some function $g$ for which one can easily rewrite $g(n)$ as
$$f(1/n)-f(0)$$ for some $f$ differentiable at 0.

In all these cases one can try to replace $g(n)=f(1/n)-f(0)$ with $f'(0)/n$ and use elementary estimates and inequalities for the remainder error, if needed (sometimes a limit comparison test will already suffice).

For example, in the problem here, $g(n)=2^{1/n}-1$ so blatantly we can try $f(x)=2^x$. We have $f'(0)=\ln 2$, which is the estimate that appears in acarchau's answer.

For another example, $\sum_n\sin(1/n)$ diverges: Take $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases expanding the exponential works, in this case:
$2^{\frac{1}{n}} = \exp ( \frac{\ln 2}{n} ) = 1 + \frac{\ln 2}{n} + c_n $. Where $ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 c_n  =  (\ln 2)^2 \times ( \exp ( \frac{\ln 2}{n} ) - 1 - \frac{\ln 2}{n} ) /( \frac{\ln 2}{n})^2 = \frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2}.$ So, $c_n$ converges absolutely.
Now, $\sum_{ n \geq 1} (-1)^n (2^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1) = \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n c_n$, which clearly converges.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the alternating series test is the right way to go.  All you have to do is prove that $\lim (2^{1 \over n} - 1)$ is zero.  That is, to employ the test, you *don't* need to show that the limit of the *series* is zero, but merely that the limit of the *summands* is zero.

[ETA: Arturo reminds us that one must also show that the summands strictly decrease.  But the AST is still the correct approach.]

Comment: No, you also need $2^{1/(n+1)}-1\le 2^{1/n}-1$ for all

Comment: @ACW: You need to show *both* that the limit is zero, *and* that the sequence is eventually decreasing.

Comment: large enough $n$.